# How to customize Scandit barcode scanner for my Android app?

Tags: android, barcode, qr-code, barcode-scanner, android-screen-support

In small screens (2.7 inch) Scandit scanner window is too thin and rotated. I want to resize it, and, perhaps, move title from top to left or right.

Which methods should I use for it?

Comment: You can create your own custom overlay view where you have full control over the elements in your scan view. https://docs.scandit.com/5.3/android/android-customize-scanui.html